# Possibility of a shorter period of a function

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Consider the function:

$$f(x)=4\cos^4\left(\frac{x-\pi}{4\pi^2}\right)-2\cos\left(\frac{x-\pi}{2\pi^2}\right)$$

One could immediately say that the period of this function is $\boxed{8\pi^3}$ which is the LCM of the period two individual functions. However the actual period of this function is $\boxed{2\pi^3}$ which can be verified by simplifying the function to

$$f(x)=\frac12\cos\left(\frac{x}{\pi^2}-\frac1\pi\right) + \frac32$$

---

How can I verify that the period I found naively is actually the shortest possible period considering the fact that one cannot always foresee such "nice" simplifications?

Comment: I don't think that there is a fits-all solution to this. Also, there exist periodic functions which don't even admit a shortest possible period; consider for example $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=0$ else. Then every rational number is a period of $f$.

Comment: How did you get $8\pi^3$ by the LCM method? I get $4\pi^3$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a much better way than resorting to the definition and solving

$$f(t+T)=f(t)$$ for $T$ and keeping the smallest positive solution. Anyway, if $f$ is a combination of functions of known periods, the period will divide the $LCM$.

To illustrate, consider the functions
$$16\cos^5x-20\cos^3 x+5\cos x$$

and

$$16\cos^5x-21\cos^3 x+5\cos x$$

which have periods $\dfrac{2\pi}5$ and $2\pi$ respectively.

Comment: >if f is a combination of functions of known periods, the period will divide the LCM. , proof this?