# Fundamental Period of $\sin \big(\frac{3x}{5}\big) + \sec \big(\frac{2x}{7}\big) + \big\{\frac{2x}{\pi}\big\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, periodic-functions

> Find the fundamental period of $$\sin \bigg(\frac{3x}{5}\bigg) + \sec \bigg(\frac{2x}{7}\bigg) + \bigg\{\frac{2x}{\pi}\bigg\}$$ where $\{\cdot\}$ is the fractional part function.

Hello,

I solved this problem using LCM approach.

Period of $\sin \big(\frac{3x}{5}\big) = 2 \pi \cdot \frac{5}{3} = \frac{10 \pi}{3}$

Period of $\sec \big(\frac{2x}{7}\big) = 7 \pi$

Period of $\big\{\frac{2x}{\pi}\big\} = \frac{\pi}{2}$

LCM = $70 \pi$.

So, $70 \pi$ is the period of this function, but I have trouble proving that this is the fundamental period. Is this the fundamental period, and if so, how can we prove this?

Thanks.

Comment: If the individual periods are fundamental periods, then the final period is also fundamental.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I don't think always. Consider $|\sin x| + |\cos x|$

Comment: Okay, that’s something I didn’t think of

Comment: I have asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131836/possibility-of-a-shorter-period-of-a-function) some time ago.

Comment: Obviously the smallest period must be a multiple of the distance between the vertical asymptotes, which is....

Comment: It seems unlikely that these functions could cancel out and make a  smaller period. However, you should just use the definition $f(x+t)=f(x)$ to solve for the minimal positive $t$.